# wpa_cli doesn't manage alternate wpa_supplicant.conf files

Tags: systemd-networkd

Following the instructions from [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge) I have created wlan0 and access point networks, but wpa_cli doesn't allow me to edit the configuration

The system creates /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf

This doesn't allow editing with wpa_cli.  Is there a way to configure wpa_cli to use the different .conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way and the [man page](https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/wpa_cli.html) does not give an option for this.

I used a small shell script to create a symbolic link / soft link to the actual file I needed to change then ran the commands.

From memory something like this:

```
ln -s /etc/wpa_supplicant/my_file.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_cli status
```